# initWithContentsOfURL: encoding: error: vs stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding: error:

Tags: objective-c

There are two ways to get content of web page html. Which should I use? Is there some advice how to use both by situation?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.co.jp/"];
NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
//NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", content);
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` and `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error` is that the former returns a retained object and the latter returns an autoreleased object. If you're using ARC, there is no semantic difference.

You should not allocate an `NSError` object for either method, you should always initialize it to `nil`:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

This is because the method you are passing `&error` into does not know how to handle a prepouplated object and your object will leak.

Finally, because you are loading data off of a web page, you should use neither `NSString` method, but you should be using a group of classes mentioned in [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). Most notably, `NSURLRequest`.